# How to limit a drop down list in a combo box to only show the values that include the letters that the user typed?

Tags: vba, list, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010 database. I have a combo box that gives me a full list of equipment numbers (they have letters and numbers i.e.: sdp1234).

To try to speed up the database I was told to limit the drop down lists in combo boxes.

Currently, users can start typing the equipment # and an item from the list will be highlighted matching with their typed characters.

I want the users to be able to type "12" and the list show should have only the values between "sdp1200" and "sdp1299". Or even just all the items that have "12" inside.

I am not sure if this is done in VBA or in the properties tab for the combo box.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question (edit) with own effort. E.g read the related section (at right site of page ). . Another hint: your task is called 'search as you type'. Query the web for that (with leading ms access),

Answer (score 2):

Well a solution would be :
Put this on the top of your VBA..just under Option ...

```vb
Dim comboboxOriginal As String
```

Put this code in the Change Event

```vb
Private Sub cboFilterAsType_Change()
If Len(Nz(comboboxOriginal, "")) = 0 Then 
    comboboxOriginal = Me.cboFilterAsType.RowSource
End If
If Len(Me.cboFilterAsType.Text) > 1 Then
    Me.cboFilterAsType.SelStart = Len(Me.cboFilterAsType.Text)
    Me.cboFilterAsType.RowSource = Replace(comboboxOriginal, ";", "") & " WHERE SOMEFIELD like ""*" & Me.cboFilterAsType.Text & "*"""
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Me.cboFilterAsType.Requery
    Me.cboFilterAsType.Dropdown
End If
End Sub
```

TO clear the filtering

```vb
Private Sub cboFilterAsType_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
If Len(Nz(comboboxOriginal, "")) > 0 Then 
    Me.cboFilterAsType.RowSource = comboboxOriginal
End If
End Sub
```

Take a note that the RowSource should be something simple like SELECT SomeID From ATable

Comment: +1 for Len-pattern! Additionally you should add [Option Explicit](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx). Instead of`""`I prefer`vbNullString`.because it is typo-safe.  Code should be indented, single-line`If`staements are hard to read and [syntax-highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) is far easier with [code-fences](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)